# Using seaborn how do I plot a column which has 70+ categories

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot a column from a dataframe. There are about 8500 rows and the `Assignment group` column has about 70+ categories. How do I plot this visually using seaborn to get some meaningful output?

```
nlp_data['Assignment group'].hist(figsize=(17,7))
```

[I used the hist() method to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6OY6.png)

Comment: Plotting will be based on visualization  you are conceptualizing. Can I know what exactly you want to show in graph?

Answer (score 0):

you can use heatmap for such data
seaborn.heatmap